# GIT Submodules in VSTS online?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules

I have a VSTS project with a git repo. The repo has some submodules that are also required as part of the software projects development.

Is there a way to create submodules inside the same VSTS project? The other option would be to split the development tasks between a VSTS project for the submodule and the project using the submodule which isn't ideal as there's a lot of overlap between the two as far as devleopment goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add multiple Git repositories to your VSTS Project. And you can push a repository that references another through submodules.

In the Code hub, expand the repository and click <kbd>New Repository</kbd>:

[image]

Use the second repository to store your submodules and reference it from the first repo. The submodule setup all happens locally on your local git repository, use whatever tool you prefer or the command-line and then push the repositories to VSTS.

Comment: How do I store the submodule reference in my second repository?

Comment: Use `git submodule add <path> https://youraccount.visualstudio.com/Project/_git/Repo` after running `git submodule init` if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: oh I mean, I have a vsts git repo of the submodule, how do I make that repo the repo for the 'new repoistory' in this project?